# Where is the _socket file?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm looking through python built in library modules, and for example in `socket.py` I see the line:

```
import _socket
```

I understand that the socket module acts as a wrapper for `_socket`.  I want to read through some of the source code files within `_socket` to see how certain tasks are accomplished.

Where can I find `_socket` or any of these other shared files on a Linux box?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`_socket` is a C extension. The `socket.py` module wraps this with some additional information that doesn't need the speed boost or access to OS-level C APIs.

If you are versed in C, you can read the [`socketmodule.c` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/socketmodule.c).

There is no one-on-one mapping between the final `.so` or `.dll` file and the original source file however. You can grep the [`setup.py` file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/setup.py) for the names instead:

```
exts.append( Extension('_socket', ['socketmodule.c'],
                       depends = ['socketmodule.h']) )
```

Take into account however that some modules are *built-in*, compiled as part of the `python` binary; these are all listed in the [`sys.builtin_module_names` tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `__file__` attribute:

```
In [11]: _socket.__file__
Out[11]: '/Users/andy/.miniconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-35m-darwin.so'
```

In python packages you can also use the `__path__` attribute (for the directory):

```
In [12]: yapf.__file__
Out[12]: '/Users/andy/.miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yapf/__init__.py'

In [13]: yapf.__path__
Out[13]: ['/Users/andy/.miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/yapf']
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you where to find the C source code however.

Comment: When calling magic method file it gives absolute directory to the dynamic lib not the source. The source can be found in the Python repository github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.c github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/socketmodule.h